# Mismatch in dependencies during Gradle plugin execution

Tags: gradle, plugins

I'm developing the [graphql-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/graphql-java-generator/graphql-gradle-plugin-project). I have an issue with Spring Framework 6, during plugin execution.

The plugin is compiled with Spring Framework 5.

When using the plugin, with a Spring Boot 2 and a Spring Framework 5, everything runs fine. If a I do a `gradlew buildEnvironment`, the (partial) result is:

```
classpath
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql:2.7.10
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.7.10
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.7.10
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.26
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.26
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.26
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.26
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.26
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.26 (*)
```

The issue appears, when the project that uses the plugin has a Spring Boot 3 dependency, for instance like this:

```
plugins {
    id "com.graphql-java-generator.graphql-gradle-plugin" version "local-SNAPSHOT"
    id 'java'
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "3.0.6"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version "1.1.0"
}
```

Then, there is a mess in Spring Framework dependencies:

```
|         |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.26
|         |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.26
|         |    |         |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.26
|         |    |         |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.26 -> 6.0.8
|         |    |         |    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:6.0.8
```

spring-context, spring-aop and spring-beans remain in version 5.3.26.
spring-core is in version 6.0.8.

The issue is that this causes various `ClassNotFoundException`, on classes from spring-core that are used in the 5.3.26 spring framework, but have been removed in spring-core 6.0.8.

So my question is: ***how to make the plugin work, whatever spring framework dependencies are used by other Gradle plugins ?***

I would like to make the plugin easy to use, to that **no change is necessary in the build.gradle of projects** that use the `graphql-gradle-plugin` plugin

I see these solutions:

- Add the missing classes in the plugin code. It was worth a try, but it leads to class incompatibilities.
- Deliver two publish two different plugins, graphql-gradle-plugin and graphql-gradle-plugin3 . One for Spring Boot 2, and one for Spring Boot 3.

  - But I'd prefer to avoid that. I would have to create a graphql-gradle-pluginXxxx each time a new incompatibility appears?
- Use the Gradle Variant capability.

  - A variant for Spring Boot 3 would add the necessary Spring Framework 6 or Spring Boot 3 dependency.
  - But I didn't understand how to do this in this use case.
- Add a `buildScript` that loads the Spring Framework 6 dependency, like in this [build.gradle](https://github.com/graphql-java-generator/GraphQL-Forum-Gradle-Tutorial-server/blob/master/build.gradle).

  - But I'm looking for a solution with no impact on the build.gradle file of the project that uses the graphql-gradle-plugin

The [Resolving gradle plugin dependency conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101067/resolving-gradle-plugin-dependency-conflicts) gives a solution, but it implies changing the build.gradle file of the project that uses the graphql-gradle-plugin